# Помогите разобраться с установкой RTEMS

Tags: python, mingw

Всем бобра) Подскажите пожалуйста, мужики, что мне делать с Вот Этим под названием RTEMS 4.11 ??? Кто знаком? У кого была эта чудо-операционка? Уже второй день не могу даже исходники заполучить, не понимаю вообще. У них еще сайт плохо обновляется (похоже застой), инфа устарела, сейчас исходники собираются у юзеров на машинах, а не скачиваются с сайта, к сожалению... Так вот у меня проблема возникла: Python выдает ошибку, мол

```
proglyk@PronyashinIN-34 MINGW32 /development/rtems/4.11/src/source-builder/source-builder
$ ./sb-check
error: no hosts defaults found; please add MINGW32_NT-6.1
```

в исходниках это сборщика на питоне нет варианта на mingw32, сами смотрите:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    try:
        import windows
        overrides = windows.load()
        host_windows = True
        host_posix = False
    except:
        raise error.general('failed to load Windows host support')
elif os.name == 'posix':
    uname = os.uname()
    try:
        if uname[0].startswith('MINGW64_NT'):
            import windows
            overrides = windows.load()
            host_windows = True
        elif uname[0].startswith('CYGWIN_NT'):
            import windows
            overrides = windows.load()
        elif uname[0] == 'Darwin':
            import darwin
            overrides = darwin.load()
        elif uname[0] == 'FreeBSD':
            import freebsd
            overrides = freebsd.load()
        elif uname[0] == 'NetBSD':
            import netbsd
            overrides = netbsd.load()
        elif uname[0] == 'Linux':
            import linux
            overrides = linux.load()
        elif uname[0] == 'SunOS':
            import solaris
            overrides = solaris.load()
    except error.general as ge:
        raise error.general('failed to load %s host support: %s' % (uname[0], ge))
    except:
        raise error.general('failed to load %s host support' % (uname[0]))
else:
    raise error.general('unsupported host type; please add')
if overrides is None:
    raise error.general('no hosts defaults found; please add %s' % (uname[0]))
```

И что же мне делать?

Comment: А если использовать флаг `MINGW64`? ... Хотя, я так понимаю, сборка под линухом идет? Тогда логичнее флаг `Linux` использовать.

Comment: Ну так у меня 32. Я не знаю что будет. Попробую сейчас, спасибо

Comment: https://github.com/RTEMS/rtems-source-builder/blob/master/doc/source-builder.txt - если это оно, то там много чего расписано. Нужно по шагам делать. Там и описание ситуаций есть.

Comment: Все равно не выходит. Я вот знаешь чего не понимаю... Вот зачем такой огород городить, если в итоге ничего не работает? Почему нельзя было как у фриртоса просто распространять исходники? Нет, надо Вот Такое сделать, написать кучу мануалов где показано что все ок, но на деле возникают вообще непонятные ошибки. Говно. Вот и всё. Нечего мне с этим барахлом возиться. Позор((((

Comment: msys2 заносит в значение, читаемое в скрипте командойuname = os.uname()

Comment: msys2 заносит в значение, читаемое в скрипте командой 
uname = os.uname() значение MINGW64_NT-6.1 и все! Я не знаю как его поменять. Не знаю я питона. :((